# Using a python variable in a html form

Tags: python, cgi

I'm not sure whether you can do this or not, so I just wanted to ask.
I have variables on my python file and I want to send them to another python file to use. So for instance

```
username= "John250"
passw = "pass"
```

Now I believe I need to change the value of each input type for this to work, but I'm scratching my head over what to change it to.

```
print ("""
    <form name="myform" class="myform" action="index1.py" method ="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="Username" value = "Hi">
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value = "Hi">
    </form>
""")
```

Any ideas?? 
(I'm using js to submit the form automatically hence why there is no submit button)

Comment: You probably want to look at a [templating engine](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating#Templating_Engines), although your question isn't that clear.

Comment: What will be sending the variables from one python module to another? Where does the HTML come into it?

Comment: Basically I want to send the variables created from one python file to the other. So lets say the code above is index0.py and I want to send them via a html form to index1.py. So if I was to print them out on the screen, I would need to use form=cgi.FieldStorage() and then user = form.getvalue("Username") and then print(user) to print the username on the screen. If that makes sense?